# How do I rename each .jpg file name with consecutive numbers in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm completely new to PowerShell, or any shell for that matter. I'm trying to figure out a way to rename 109 photos that are marked IMG_3571 to IMG_3679. I want to number them consecutively starting at 236. I've tried a few things and this is where I am at right now:

`Get-ChildItem "C:\Files to Transfer\test"*.jpg | ForEach-Object -begin {$count=236} -process {rename-item -Path "C:\Files to Transfer\test" -NewName "$count"}`

I get this error message 108 times:

```
At line:1 char:95
+ ... } -process {rename-item -Path "C:\Files to Transfer\test" -NewName "$ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Also the file named "test" (where all the photos are contained) gets changed to 236...

Edit: I would like to have the files without "IMG" in the name. Only the numbers.

Thanks everyone! Here is what did it:

`Get-ChildItem "C:\Files to Transfer\test\*.jpg" | ForEach-Object -begin {$count=236} -process {rename-item -Path $_.fullname -NewName "$count.jpg";$count++}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close.

You need $_ in the rename. $_ is the pipeline variable that Get-ChildItem is feeding. 
Your output file needs IMG- as a prefix
And you need to increment count.

Try this:

`Get-ChildItem "C:\Files to Transfer\test\*.jpg" | ForEach-Object -begin {$count=236} -process {rename-item -Path $_.fullname -NewName "$count.jpg";$count++}`

It is very useful to add -WhatIf to things you are trying so that you can see what will happen without actually doing it.

Comment: i think you need `$_.fullname` to rename the file. also you should explain the `-Whatif` parameter

Comment: Good point.  I used -WhatIf to test my version and forgot to delete it.

Comment: @GrendleM I'm sorry, I should have specified that I did not want the "IMG" in the name. I just wanted the number. Also, it turned all of the photos into some kind of generic "file" type and the images are no longer shown as thumbnails.

Comment: NewName is missing the file extension. Should be "$count.jpg" (Following comment to remove IMG_)